# NUBS falling off OKRA PLANT

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, okra

I have healthy okra plants based on leaves and trunk observation, with small buds that are taking too long to blossom. They are planted in 5 liter pots.

I found 1 flower that has dried up and fallen and it revealed a nub. Today, I found out that the small nub fell off.

I live here in the Philippines and it is pretty hot. I water them everyday with quantity of maybe 2 cups of water as I was informed they don't like too much water... I water them with blackstrap molasses once or twice a week and have used rabbit manure to fertilize the soil , leaves are green , no holes or any signs of pests infestation.

[image]

this bud fell off. this is the second one.

What seems to be the problem?